# AJAX live search does not always contain the full value in the search box

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm setting up a basic AJAX live search for my website but I am encountering an issue where sometimes the whole value of my search box is not being captured properly.

For instance, if I type 'roll' into the search box, sometimes it will return the values for 'ro' instead. This is the most common occurrence as seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PwnO.jpg

I say most common occurrence because in the link above, you will see different values captured even though 'roll' is the value of search box for each result. The last image being the desired result. It's as if I type the value in too fast, because I can not reproduce the issue when slowly typing each character.

In desperation I have tried different events, such as keyup, keydown, changed, keypress .on('Keyup') etc. Logging the javascript variable to the console shows the incorrect value, so the sql statement is obviously returning the wrong results (as seen in the album above).

My index.php basically consists of every result before anything is searched:

```
<ul id="search-results" class="grid cs-style-2 justify-content-center">
    $cosmetic->getCard($result);
</ul>
```

Here is the gist of my ajax.php file:

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Cosmetics WHERE Name LIKE '%$search%' OR Type LIKE '%$search%' OR Rarity LIKE '%$search%' OR CostOrigin LIKE '%$search%' OR ImageName LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY FIELD(Rarity,'legendary','epic','rare','uncommon','common'), Name";
    echo($sql);
    $result = $connection->query($sql);
    $cosmetic->getCard($result);
}
```

and here is the script.js file that is included in the index.php:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
           var name = document.getElementById("search").value;
           console.log(name);
           if (name !== " ") {
               $.post('/test/ajax.php',{search:name}, function(data){
                   $("#search-results").html(data);
           });
        }
    });
});
```

In this album: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PwnO.jpg I expect the results to be the last image where it actually queries the correct word, instead of capturing other or no values from the search box.

Comment: As you aren't waiting for the whole string to be typed before you start processing it, I think you are having timing problems. I'm wondering what would happen if you simply ran the getElementById and ajax call twice in your function, so that the second call processed the search string as it stood when the first call had finished? Worth a try I think.

Comment: Unfortunately seems to still be an issue. I definitely agree though, it does seem to be a timing issue and I tried testing that too, but I don't think it's working. I had var name = $(this).delay(300).val();

Comment: A delay in the script isn't going to help because control is still with the script. You need the script to be releasing control. Have you got the ajax running asynchronously?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but isn't it asynchronous by default?

Comment: I don't know, because I don't use JQuery, sorry.

Comment: Yes it is. The A in ajax stands for asynchronous. So it's defaulted.

Comment: Sorry, you have reached the limit of my knowledge on this ... let's see what others come up with.

Comment: Thank you for the help thus far!

Comment: Might be worth checking that the async-ness of Ajax (i.e. ability to populate the screen without reloading) also implies that your script doesn't wait for the php to complete - I am not clear whether your code waits, or whether it sets an event handler to pick up the php output - I was thinking of the latter meaning of 'async' not the former - maybe they go together anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This query should output them in the correct order.
First items: Exact match to search term
Next items: Items that start with search term
Third items: All items that include search term

```
SELECT * 
FROM Cosmetics 
WHERE Name LIKE '%$search%' 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN name = '$search' THEN 1 WHEN name LIKE '$search%' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END);
```

Comment: Hi Ralph. Thank you, but the issue isn't the order they're in. It's the value being captured from the search box isn't always the whole value.